# SQL Server 2012 Query Performance

Tags: sql-server-2012

I will be starting a project soon using SQL Server 2012 where I will be required to provide real-time querying of database tables in excess of 4 billion records in 1 of the tables alone. I am fairly familiar with SQL Server (I have indexes on the relevant columns), but have never had to deal with databases so large before.

I have been looking into partitioning and am fairly confident at using it, however it is only available in the Enterprise version(?) for which the licenses are WAY too expensive. Column Store indexes also look promising, but as well as only being in Enterprise version, they also render your table read-only(??). Another option is to archive data as soon as it is not being used in live so that I keep as little data in the live tables as possible.

The main queries on the largest table will be on a `NVARCHAR(50)` column which contains an ID. Initial testing with 4 billion records using a query to pull a single record based on the ID is taking in excess of 5 mins even with indexing. So my question is (and sorry if it sounds naive!): can somebody please suggest a way to speed up the queries on this table that I haven't mentioned (and therefore don't know about)? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't sound right. Assuming 100 index records per page the index will only need 6 or 7 levels to support 4 billion rows so I can't see how that takes 5 minutes for a singleton seek. How many logical reads are showing? What wait types show up during the 5 minutes?

Comment: 5 minutes for a single record to be returned does indeed seem like a long time, my bet would be that the indexes you have either aren't being used, some statistics are out of date or you have an IO issue perhaps.  Can you post the actual execution plan for the query for us to have a look at?